# How to insert searchable value for PDF reader?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste

In a dictionary a headword can consist of special characters like in this example : **Eyja·fjalla··jök|ull**. I would like to achieve that the user in PDF reader in PDF file can search for **Eyjafjallajökull** (the headword without the special characters).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very naive, but easy to generalize. Final definition should have two parameters and take maximum of two lengths.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}          

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\newlength\eyja
\settowidth{\eyja}{Eyjafjallajökull}
In a dictionary a headword can consist of special characters like in this example
\makebox[\eyja]{\color{white}Eyjafjallajökull}\hspace{-\eyja}Eyja·fjalla··jök|ull. 
I would like to achieve that the user in PDF reader in PDF file can search for
Eyjafjallajökull (the headword without the special characters).


\end{document}
```

Alas, I cannot add the resulting PDF here. Tested only under Acrobat Reader.

**Updated:** - Preview in Evince.
[image: Search in PDF]

Comment: Works in Sumatrapdf.

Comment: It works in Evince too. If I understand it correctly, I should set the width each time new headword appears, so the box corresponds to the width of the headword.

Comment: If you just want searchable and are okay with the headword being slightly off (in terms of the highlighted parts when you search), you can just use `\rlap{\color{white}Original Word}Head-word-with-symbols` instead of the `\makebox` incantation. This way you also don't need to measure the lengths.

Comment: It does not work in Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 11):

[`accsupp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) does allow for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp
\begin{document}
\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=Eyjafjallajokull}
Eyja$\cdot$fjalla$\cdot\cdot$j{\"o}k$\vert$ull
\EndAccSupp{}
\end{document}
```

While the selection might not be as expected, the search works (in Adobe Reader, at least).

Comment: Does not seem to work in Sumatrapdf.

Comment: @azetina No, only Adobe Reader supports it, AFAIK.