# /ActualText in small cap hyperlinks

Tags: xetex, hyperref, accsupp

I'm using the `frenchlinks` option for hyperref, which due to solicitous care of XeLaTeX + Linux Libertine, gives *bona fide* small-caps links on the page.  The problem is, when I cut and paste out of the generated PDF, I get Unicode small-caps out, whereas I'd prefer ASCII.

Can anyone suggest how to modify this MWE?  (Did I make a mistake in the setup?)

*Note, for the updated MWE, I've tried to patch `\href` using the accepted answer from* [Patching arguments inside a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113147/patching-arguments-inside-a-macro)  (no dice).

**Updated MWE**

```
\documentclass[article, a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont[Mapping= tex-text,  
     SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},   
     SmallCapsFeatures= {Color=FFFFFF, RawFeature={+smcp,+hlig,+dlig}},   
     BoldFont={Linux Biolinum O Bold},   
%     BoldFeatures={Color = FFFFFF,SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine Capitals O Bold},%
%       SmallCapsFeatures = { Color=FFFFFF,   RawFeature={+smcp,+hlig,+dlig}} },  
     ItalicFont={Linux Libertine O Italic},   
     ItalicFeatures={Color = FFFFFF,  %
       SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine Capitals O Italic}, %
       SmallCapsFeatures = {Color=FFFFFF}},   
     BoldItalicFont={Linux Biolinum O},   
     BoldItalicFeatures={ Color = FFFFFF, %
      SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine Capitals O Bold Italic},  %
      SmallCapsFeatures = { Color=FFFFFF,RawFeature={+smcp,+hlig,+dlig}}} ]{Linux Libertine O} 

\usepackage[linktoc=all,frenchlinks,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .5},citebordercolor={1 1 1},linkbordercolor={1 1 1},urlbordercolor={1 1 1}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\catcode`\#=12
\newcommand{\newhref}{%
\normalexpandarg%
\patchcmd{\href}{#2}{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstring,ActualText={#2}}%
 #2%
 \EndAccSupp{}%
}{}{}%
}
\catcode`\#=6

\begin{document}

Sexy tex: \newhref{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{sxe}.

\end{document}
```

**Original MWE**

```
\documentclass[article, a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont[Mapping= tex-text,  
     SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},   
     SmallCapsFeatures= {Color=FFFFFF, RawFeature={+smcp,+hlig,+dlig}},   
     BoldFont={Linux Biolinum O Bold},   
%     BoldFeatures={Color = FFFFFF,SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine Capitals O Bold},%
%       SmallCapsFeatures = { Color=FFFFFF,   RawFeature={+smcp,+hlig,+dlig}} },  
     ItalicFont={Linux Libertine O Italic},   
     ItalicFeatures={Color = FFFFFF,  %
       SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine Capitals O Italic}, %
       SmallCapsFeatures = {Color=FFFFFF}},   
     BoldItalicFont={Linux Biolinum O},   
     BoldItalicFeatures={ Color = FFFFFF, %
      SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine Capitals O Bold Italic},  %
      SmallCapsFeatures = { Color=FFFFFF,RawFeature={+smcp,+hlig,+dlig}}} ]{Linux Libertine O} 

\usepackage[linktoc=all,frenchlinks,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .5},citebordercolor={1 1 1},linkbordercolor={1 1 1},urlbordercolor={1 1 1}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xstring} % added as suggested in 1st given answer
\usepackage{accsupp}

\let\hrefold\href
\newcommand*{\hrefnew}[2]{%
\normalexpandarg%
\BeginAccSupp{method=plain,unicode,ActualText={#2}}%
\hrefold{#1}{#2}%
\EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}

Sexy tex: \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{sxe}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/is-it-possible-to-provide-alternative-text-to-use-when-copying-text-from-the-pdf ?

Comment: The only PDF viewer that understands `\AccSupp` that I know of is Adobe Reader. Are you using it?

Comment: Some people here say it works in Evince, which is what I'm using: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149581/how-to-insert-searchable-value-for-pdf-reader  (I tested the original MWE on Adobe Reader too, for good measure).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- The macro `\hrefnew` is defines with the new feature `/ActualText`, but the body is using the unmodified `\href`.
- Macro `\href` is using the undefined `\normalexpandarg` that comes from package `xstring` that is not loaded.
- If method `plain` with option `unicode` is used, then the argument must be a valid `UTF-16BE` string. In this case I would let `hyperref` do the right conversion by using method `pdfstringdef`:

  ```
  \BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,ActualText={#2}}
  ```

`\href` is not a good candidate for redefining, because of its special treatment of the first argument that is read with changed catcodes. Therefore a better candidate is the internal `\href@`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\href@old\href@
\renewcommand*{\href@}[2]{%
  \href@old{#1}{%
    \BeginAccSupp{%
      method=pdfstringdef,%
      ActualText={#2},%
    }%
      #2%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
```

Comment: I've tried to fix the MWE, but modifying the original `\href` seems like a challenge, could you give me some suggestion about how to do that?

Comment: Heiko, there may be very few people who can add more detail on this, any help would be sincerely appreciated!